# Report PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, report, helper

I apologize in advance for my bad English level.

I explain my problem ... I try to create a web interface that would handle the number of times that the employees will eat in the canteen ...

Everything works fine but I would get a report of the number of times employees. and that I hang.
In fact I have a table called "Transactions" and understand the "Transaction ID", "Surname", "Name", "Date_transaction" and "_transaction time"

How could I do to get a report in php / mysql? By selecting a specific month?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

greetings,

Ljebool

Comment: Without seeing the data or the queries that you're now using it would be hard to know how to help you. Can you setup a SQL fiddle?

Comment: Gawd, I don't know. Use a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve what you need:

**option 1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  date_transaction > '12/01/2014' 
       AND date_transaction < '01/01/2015';
```

**option 2**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  date_transaction BETWEEN '12/01/2014' AND '01/01/2015';
```

**option 3**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  Month(date_transaction) = 12;
```